# Difference between convergence and divergence in limits using L'Hopital's Rule?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm very sorry if this is extremely elementary. I'm new to L'Hopital's Rule.

I was given two problems. The first one being $lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{ln(x)}{x}$ and the second one being $lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{e^x}{x^2}$

Using L'Hopital's Rule I can see that $lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{ln(x)}{x} = lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{1/x}{1/1} = lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{x} = 0$

and I can also see that (Using L'Hopital's Rule twice in this situation):

$lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{e^x}{x^2} = lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{e^x}{2x} = lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{e^x}{2} = \infty$

The problem I'm having, however, is with my professor's solutions. In the first problem he says $f(x) = \dfrac{ln(x)}{x}$ converges to 0. In the second problem he says $f(x) = \dfrac{e^x}{x^2}$ diverges to $\infty$.

What is the difference between divergence and convergence?

Comment: Divergence means infinite limit or no limit at all. Convergence means finite limit.

Comment: Notation convention: if a sequence goes to $+\infty$, then we say that it diverges.

Comment: @user31415 post your comment as an answer? :p Very helpful to know.